# Python - Scrape text from Image (alt tags)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been using BeautifulSoup to successfuly scrape some info from a website, but I'm having problem scraping the "alt" tag from an image/link.

Here's the code I used so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.com/fc-porto/startseite/verein/720?saison_id=2017"
tree = requests.get(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

Players = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Value = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
Age = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
Team = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"})
```

I'm having problems with the last line, as it extracts the entire tooltip info and I only need the text contained in the "alt" tag. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what kind of information team should hold. Just going by your question - *"I only need the text contained in the "alt" tag"* - this should work.

```
imgs = [a.find('img') for a in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"}) if a.find('img')]
team = [img.get('alt') for img in imgs]
```

Get all `img` tags nested under `a` tags then get `alt` attribute from each `img`.

```
Output:

['Olympiacos Piraeus',
 'FC Porto',
 'FC Famalicão',
 'Omonia Nicosia',
 'Atlético Madrid',
 'FC Porto',
 'Tigres UANL',
 'Zenit St. Petersburg',
 'Kasimpasa',
 'FC Porto',
 'FC Porto B',
 'Leicester City',
 'Manchester United',
 'CF Monterrey',
 'FC Porto',
 'Vorskla Poltava',
 'Atlético Madrid',
 'Sevilla FC',
 'FC Porto',
 'Vitória Guimarães SC',
 'Varzim SC',
 'Portimonense SC',
 'FC Porto',
 'FC Porto',
 'Hebei China Fortune',
 'UD Las Palmas',
 'Al Rayyan Sports Club',
 'SC Braga',
 'Levante UD',
 'FC Porto',
 'FC Porto',
 'FC Porto',
 'Eintracht Frankfurt',
 'RC Strasbourg Alsace',
 'Real Zaragoza',
 'FC Porto',
 'SL Benfica',
 'Sporting CP',
 'SC Braga',
 'Rio Ave FC',
 'GD Chaves',
 'CS Marítimo',
 'Vitória Guimarães SC',
 'FC Porto']
```

Not sure if this is the output you expect

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
Team = [a.find('img').get('alt') for a in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "vereinprofil_tooltip"}) if a.find('img')]
```

---

```
['Olympiacos Piraeus', 'FC Porto', 'FC Famalicão', 'Omonia Nicosia', 'Atlético Madrid', 'FC Porto', 'Tigres UANL', 'Zenit St. Petersburg', 'Kasimpasa', 'FC Porto', 'FC Porto B', 'Leicester City', 'Manchester United', 'CF Monterrey', 'FC Porto', 'Vorskla Poltava', 'Atlético Madrid', 'Sevilla FC', 'FC Porto', 'Vitória Guimarães SC', 'Varzim SC', 'Portimonense SC', 'FC Porto', 'FC Porto', 'Hebei China Fortune', 'UD Las Palmas', 'Al Rayyan Sports Club', 'SC Braga', 'Levante UD', 'FC Porto', 'FC Porto', 'FC Porto', 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'RC Strasbourg Alsace', 'Real Zaragoza', 'FC Porto', 'SL Benfica', 'Sporting CP', 'SC Braga', 'Rio Ave FC', 'GD Chaves', 'CS Marítimo', 'Vitória Guimarães SC', 'FC Porto']
```